# how to configure ojdbc6 driver in grails 3.0.7?

Tags: grails-3.0

Here is my application.yml

```
dataSources:
  dataSource:
    loggingSql: true
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password:

    environments:
     development:
      dataSources:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: validate
            url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1521/mydb            driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
            dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
            jndiName: java:comp/env/jdbc/devapp
```

---

```
grails.naming.entries:

    jdbc:
          devapp:
            type: javax.sql.DataSource
            driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
            url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1521/mydb
            username: "username"
            password: "password"
            properties:
              maxActive: 20
              maxIdle: 4
              initialSize: 4
              maxWait: -1
```

And here is my build.gradle entries:

```
 runtime "oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0.4.0"
```

Build fails with the following error.

> Error Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':testRuntime'. Type 'gradle dependencies' for more information

Comment: why runtime? should it not be compile? I have it as compile time dependency and it works correctly.

Comment: compile didn't work. Can you please post the maven repo entry, dependency entry and application.yml entries?

Answer (score 1):

When I placed the following dependency in build.gradle, it worked.

compile 'com.oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0.3'